# Purpose of ida-prefixed appSettings keys in web.config

Tags: .net, azure, web-config, adfs, wif

I am developing web applications that are protected by [WIF 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/security/wif-overview), the new 
Visual Studio templates will add the following keys to the web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://example.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
  <add key="ida:Realm" value="https://example.com/applications/serviceapp/" />
  <add key="ida:AudienceUri" value="https://example.com/applications/serviceapp/" />
```

As well as the typical `system.IdentityModel` Tags:

```
<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
        <audienceUris>
            <add value="https://example.com/applications/serviceapp/" />
        </audienceUris>
        <securityTokenHandlers>
            <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        </securityTokenHandlers>
        <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
        <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
            <authority name="http://example.com/adfs/services/trust">
                <keys>
                    <add thumbprint="3aa0dee165bec459a472aa611cc19453abd61f08" />
                </keys>
                <validIssuers>
                    <add name="http://example.com/adfs/services/trust" />
                </validIssuers>
            </authority>
        </issuerNameRegistry>
    </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
<system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
        <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />
        <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://example.com/adfs/ls/" realm="https://example.com/applications/serviceapp/" requireHttps="true" />
    </federationConfiguration>
</system.identityModel.services>
```

My questions is, what is the purpose of the ida-prefixed `appSettings` keys as the seem not be used at all and contain redundant information (because it has to be declared in `system.identityModel` anyways).

I've googled and found this article:
[Identity in your own apps with Windows Azure Active Directory](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2014/01/20/identity-in-your-own-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory/)

There it's written:

> First, we got two new sections: system.identityModel and system.identityModel.services with some data in it. AppSettings have been extended with keys like “ida:FederationMetadataLocation” and so on. The prefix “ida” stands for Identity and Authorization. These values are important for identifiying our app. ...  ida:AudienceUri and ida:Realm is the Unique ID of our app (in URL-format). ida:FederationMetadataLocation is the address of the XML-document where we get the endpoints for login and logout.

There is no clear statement, when this information is used. Maybe the ida tags are only used when hosted on Windows Azure? For the record: Our applications, including the ADFS, are all On-Premises. 
Can I simply delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the "ida" keys are used by the VS plugin and other tools.  They allow you to use the plugin/tools to update the WIF-related configuration in your web.Config.  This is handy if the key or something else changes.  It must be said that the new owin pipeline takes this one step further by downloading the metadata document on startup so that you app is always up to date.
IMHO your appliction doesn't need them and you can delete them.

Answer (score 1):

They are used by WIF / OWIN to get the metadata e.g. the signing certificate and to set up the signin / signon information e.g. wtrealm.

Comment: I did see some implementations on github or MSDN articles like this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet - But I could not find out, why they are not accessing the information through system.identityModel. 
From what I can say is that deleting those keys in our web-applications did not have any effect on WIF, so I don't think that WIF is using it.

Comment: If you use pure WIF i.e. all the parameters e.g. thumbprint configured in web.config than you don't need it. However, when you add WIF via OWIN, OWIN uses the metadata address to get all of this automatically.